# Async function result

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This can show the results on the console, not on the web.
Anybody can let me know how to get async results.
getAsset() has async function getAssetById() and it works good.
But this doesn't show the results.

```html
    <template>
        <div id="myhome">
            <div id="myhome-item" class="col-5">
                <div id="component">
                    <div id="title" class="text-white bg-primary"><h5>Asset Detail</h5></div>
                    {{ getAsset }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import apis from '../services/api-services';
    
    export default {
        components: {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                asset: Object,
                assetId: this.$route.params.id
            }
        },
        computed: {
            getAsset() {
                apis.getAssetById(this.$route.params.id, this.tb.JWT)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    return res;
                });
            },
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this needs to be an async method, async computed are not handled by vue vanilla, you'd need a plugin for those.

The first return defines the value of `apiResponse` then, the 2nd return
of  `apiResponse` defines the return value of the method itself

```js
methods: {
  async getAsset() {
    const apiResponse = await apis.getAssetById(this.$route.params.id, this.tb.JWT)
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    });
    return apiResponse  
  },
},
```